# Как выделить фигуру если у неё несколько граней и она под наклоном

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]> Как прописать в css файл многогранную фигуру, которая находиться под наклоном. У меня уже есть пример квадрата. Как сделать выделение другой фигуры. В html я знаю как сделать а вот в css затрудняюсь. Это не мой пример, но он самый актуальный для меня.

```css
.image-map {
  width: 489px;
  height: 626px;
  position: relative;
}

.image-map ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.image-map a:link,
.image-map a:visited {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.image-map a span {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -1000em;
}

.hand1 a {
  left: 335px;
  top: 270px;
}

.hand2 a {
  left: 300px;
  top: 185px;
}

.hand3 a {
  left: 270px;
  top: 110px;
}

.leg1 a {
  left: 245px;
  top: 255px;
}

.leg2 a {
  left: 245px;
  top: 380px;
}

.leg3 a {
  left: 255px;
  top: 520px;
}

.image-map a:hover span,
.image-map a:focus span {
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  top: 4em;
  left: 26px;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  margin-left: -2.5em;
}

.image-map a:hover,
.image-map a:focus {
  border: 1px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="margin.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image-map">
    <img src="eb52209196ba.jpg" alt="тело">
    <ul>
      <li class="hand1"><a href="#"><span>Кисть</span></a></li>
      <li class="hand2"><a href="#"><span>Локоть</span></a></li>
      <li class="hand3"><a href="#"><span>Плечо</span></a></li>
      <li class="leg1"><a href="#"><span>Бедро</span></a></li>
      <li class="leg2"><a href="#"><span>Колено</span></a></li>
      <li class="leg3"><a href="#"><span>Стопа</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Не понятно что вам нужно, вы хотите чтобы вместо квадрата был круг, шестиугольник я так понимаю?

Comment: Еще если не сложно, скинте картинку человека, так не понятно

Comment: Duoxx, добавил фото